# How to calculate Under root in Following Expression

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an expression `v((P1*P46)/3600)` where p1 comes from one textbox and p46 comes from another textbox

> eg: `v((2.0*3.2)/3600)`

How can I calculate it?

Here is my code:

```
Private Function calculatevitalexpression(ByVal strformulla As String, ByRef numtxt As TextBox, ByRef dtable As DataTable)
    Try
     strformulla =v((2.0*3.2)/3600)
        Dim Sc As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl
        Sc.Language = "VBSCRIPT"
        strformulla = RemoveCharacter(strformulla, "P")
        Dim res As Double = Convert.ToDouble(Sc.Eval(strformulla))
        Dim result As Decimal = Math.Round(res, decimalplaces)
        numtxt.Text = result

     Finally
        'frmW.Close()
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that using the `ScriptControl` component, you would have to pass all the possible input values into the control via `AddObject`, so that the script-control knows what `P1` and `P46` *are* - for example (using C# for the example):

```
foreach(var control in Controls) {
    if(control is TextBox &&
        control.Name.StartsWith("P"))
    { // ^^^ some crude way of finding the candidates
        Sc.AddObject(control.Name, double.Parse(control.Text), false);
    }
}
```

This adds all the `P...` controls that are text-boxes, along with a numeric version of their text value.

Note: don't remove the `P` (your `RemoveCharacter` line) - otherwise all the script sees is `v((1*46)/3600)` - which doesn't involve your inputs *at all*.

However, there are standalone expression evaluation engines available that may do the job, but you'd still need to tell them the external values.